# Store information to a txt file in node js

Tags: node.js

I have this simple could that takes a users information and doesn't do much else with it.
I need to be able to take the user information and then store it to a txt file that gets created for it.

Any ideas on how i could do that? I tried for a long time and didn't get it to work and only made it worse.

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="/">
    <input type="text" name="user[name]">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="user[email]">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
  
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const app = express(); 
   
var PORT = process.env.port || 3000; 
  
// View Engine Setup 
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname)) 
app.set("view engine", "ejs") 
  
app.get("/", function(req, res){ 
      
    // Sample date to be filled in form 
    var user = { 
        email: 'test@gmail.com', 
        name: 'Gourav', 
        mobile: 9999999999, 
        address: 'ABC Colony, House 23, India'
    } 
  
    res.render("SampleForm", 
        { 
            user: user 
        } 
    ); 
}) 
   
app.listen(PORT, function(error){ 
    if(error) throw error 
    console.log("Server created Successfully on PORT", PORT) 
})
```

Comment: Where's your POST handler with the code that tries to persist the data?

Comment: use a package which can read/write json, [conf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/conf) is ok.. or implement read/decode encode/write with [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html), also you need add a POST endpoint, and validation.. you should do a few more tutorials and then come back if your stuck on a specific thing.. not can you complete this code

Answer (score 0):

You have to use app.post("/route") in your JavaScript file to access the information that you want to handle using your HTML Form. After that you can able to view that data using `console.log` in your terminal and link the database with this to handle it in more effective way.